# How to redirect with when i put '\' to '/problem' in react

Tags: reactjs

#### When i type in localhost:/3000/ i want it to rederict to localhost:/3000/problem.

```
<Route path='/' element={<Header />}></Route>
```

How do i make it in react?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Route path='/' element={<Header />}></Route>
```

`element` here is the component that you want show when using `'/'` as `path`
if you want your `path` to redirect you to another path you can use this react feature :

```
<Route path='/' element={ <Navigate to="/problem" /> }></Route>
```

you should

```
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
```

if you are using React Router v5 or an older version you use `Redirect` instead

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
<Route path='/' element={ <Redirect to="/problem" /> }/>
```